# SharePoint Backup option

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, backup

My manager asked me to look for a SharePoint backup option. Do you know any suggestions for SharePoint back up both content and application?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Which product are you handling? SharePoint Server or SharePoint Online?

For SharePoint Server, it provides two backup systems: farm and granular.

The farm backup architecture in SharePoint Server starts a SQL Server backup of content and service application databases, writes configuration content to files, and also backs up the Search index files and synchronizes them with the Search database backups.

The granular backup and export architecture uses Transact-SQL queries and export calls. Granular backup and export is a more read-intensive and processing-intensive operation than farm backup.

For more detailed information, pleas check the official doc: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/backup-and-recovery-overview

For SharePoint Online, Microsoft handles the backup and restore architecture, you can restore sites, lists, items through proper process. For more complex problems, you may need to get a service request about it for more help.

Comment: Thanks Jerry, I am referring to SharePoint on Prem, so do you know any software or company does the SharePoint backup?

Comment: @Harris If you want a compete solution for that, you may turn to 3rd party tools like ShareGate. I am not quite familiar about these tools so you may need to contact them for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If SharePoint OnPrem a regular farm backup plan would do. You could always decide the backup intervals. Only on critical applications you could opt granular backup.